# Memoir : text on recto, figures on verso : Pages numbering and figures positioning almost done

Tags: floats, formatting, positioning, page-numbering, blank-page

If you have the slightest idea...

What I have already done in the formatting of my report :

- Text on recto pages only
- Figures and tables on verso pages only
- Numbering only recto pages continuously (1, 2, 3...)

I have troubles when I want to :

- Insert title page/abstract/table of contents/list of figures etc... I would like to keep the **blank verso page/text recto pages** formatting but **without numbering** and start the numbering only at the first chapter
- Put 2 figures on one verso page, one at the top and the other at the bottom without scaling out until it fits (for the image a and b)

Here is my example code, if you have any tips or whatever ! Thanks in advance !

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{monstyle}{\fancyhf{}\rfoot{\thepage}}

\DoubleSpacing
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

    \makeatletter
                \renewcommand\chapter{%\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi To remove the blank page after the \chapter
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \global\@topnum\z@
                \@afterindentfalse
                \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
    \makeatother

    \makeatletter
        \newcommand\@addfig{\relax}
        \newcommand\addfig[1]{\global\long\def\@addfig{#1}}
        \newcommand\@putfig{\@addfig\addfig{\relax}}
        \newcommand\blankpage{%
        \null
        \vfill
        \@putfig%
        \vfill
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \clearpage%
        \addtocounter{page}{-1}
        \afterpage{\blankpage}}
    \makeatother

    \makeatletter
    \def\@captype{figure}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{monstyle}

    \title{myTitle}
    \maketitle

    \begin{abstract} LOL \end{abstract}

    \tableofcontents

    \listoffigures

    \afterpage{\blankpage}

    \chapter{LOL 1}
        \section{ROFL 1}
            \subsection{GOOSE 1}

                \lipsum

                \addfig{%
                \begin{figure}[t]
                \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=1]{image-a}
                \caption{Caption}
                \end{center}
                \end{figure}}

                \addfig{%
                \begin{figure}[b]
                \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[scale=1]{image-b}
                \caption{Caption}
                \end{center}
                \end{figure}}

                \lipsum

            \subsection{GOOSE 2}

                \lipsum

        \section{ROFL 2} 

                \lipsum

                \addfig{%
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=1]{image-c}
                \caption{Caption}}

    \chapter{LOL 2} 

                \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have any links or tips or whatever?